# Global Functions on Multimodule Project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Project with Gradle Kotlin DSL with some submodules.

How can I create a function, which is available in all submodule build.gradle.kts files?

Comment: See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html